# vega-lite: enable two zoom actions

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am trying [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATooxwaZLFp2y9B46cx1BcLQGUccKJiMMEptSQ9NFBiJEEGOAg0AG1QAA80AEYJAAYkgA4AJgylAE80VMpU9IBmDKTUsQyAFiUIOBdvdlkADWS0zJyAXwUEjsokmrER0rEANhKp1Kz8wuKqrIB2VIBOVNyQBqanOXbUFOKujN7+g4llnOWk2ZAC1CKSmoqxUtLUpfrGr122gfTsic+iBEudKDUSpVUuMMtNIXMHgskuVshNbtsfi19ocAT1gaDDmJlqUljUsnU7vMSllXmIVhkxF8dlj-sdTiCBuMxDVxjUlrC4ekEY90qtSuNVktSujvs09slxpQsu9yeSlmIkuyCRJ+UlVllkeNhQtoWKeUtJUzMfKDorlTMyXyNVqButVnqavrBUljVNXpMUlkjVtZb9sXaVY71Zr8QriuKebVNvcRSSsqk+eNSla5X9bUrI2rnbH80ks6T0xC4bcUwsSRkJeMlj6Q8ybWWCw6izGzh2su70hNfekJekyxSMbnw53VU6exz8zVju7g7XIaS9WLNpOw3H7bPoy789yRuNLsO+cMajVShPQyz8-uo8Xe4qmzlxTlBTWqRmZuNKmDHcHz7Qs5yPDsBUqVZamHZV01JcUc13R8wMPEsO31KUMlvYc3huZ5pWQkClnBMlK1WMQZgg0iqh5CZVkmOFs0pRESnFUpKLeYj21I68sgoqishowYKjFRY4LGJYPzvNs8ySPjyIzSjqIw0j3i9CFk1-JdOP1IMePkxSBOUoSRJvXkliWXk4K4iEbNba0jLIkzPTMtTKAmEkNXTb9hzWACiXdQzsWMwTVN7UiJUqNVV1-ZENQlIkQuSMLTIihcFMoCpshgojWJFATpRhZLHKnVKXPC4SPNWYY6UyAVphYtcZiSBS6WklKDjStyMoJDJimk2puSraYfzY-91lhPkusySguSXJsyVeMaIIG3y2tWODlTRDJPjKlC5oWssKxWqZqt7AbpSlfUhwKhYgzEGDqVmgbjqWml3nOtbwW5cZ-puPz7shGCPxyV75u5E7lq+6kfuqPVOJhC8xg0mkIfe07Yb65IBpWfVkXJX0DUmPbZKc7E3qhj6zrhjCBpw3kG0apribTZaMeprHVoAXV6EA4FkHQ1AMMgQgXUAADMaEaNQtESJRMDyTwtAARwYJBbDoIIaFIUwkHiGholQUAnEwFx5ZAfmzYt9BEm6fnBCQPIHFQOIDpacWyCMdRxaVlX0AMTBjDCQRTCYAw5fQaBwiiUwoGEHA0B8SIlEF4XReNmJKR5pQAC82DYfx0GUeBGgAQhiOBSFsShvCMQQAGk4DyHmrf55AjAAaz95XXHQYRDFMHA2CDtBJfCBpFcLwQnCT1AU7gJQdEENgTHQABiVJJelJBSittOhbYEXZDFk3WKlmXBCjylFb7tWNa1vQnD1pQDaNv3nH7kAD5AG3v9-qCS+stLZ3wDiAdWmszY61fiAd+xtTZf0ttbJBdt27shwEgIwSAEBZ1ALIHB39I5wAVgdXu4CR5jyUNLWWWcOS5xAHIawwgoA9yUIYLBURMDJ18HAfmodIixDOBCWi6ZajPC6vZcE2QUi1TpKUbofMGGdx7uff239KG2F-unY+otxZAJADQ6+WhgLyjAd-SBT8YGuH5mwTBUA6D3FCOEQRDwHbsh8JrCAks17F3dtLWertQCayjtnYh8RKAK1AJg7BxcQDhKtnzRRSgVHkO-r4C2y82Cr3XiADektJbTFMBAHwbAu5wAAOrqE0KgaqAsj4nzPmcYBxjo73jMX-e+6BLHQJfjYh2fMgA) to zoom on a different axis by using wheel! or wheel![event.ctrlKey] to discriminate between the axis that has to be zoomed.

```
  "layer": [
    {
      "selection": {
        "grid": {
          "type": "interval",
          "bind": "scales",
          "clip": true,
          "encodings": ["x"],
          "zoom": "wheel!"
        },
        "grid": {
          "type": "interval",
          "bind": "scales",
          "clip": true,
          "encodings": ["y"],
          "zoom": "wheel![event.ctrlKey]"
        }
      },
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "point": false,
        "tooltip": true,
        "color": "#0f32a3"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "y",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": ""},
          "title": ""
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "x",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "x"},
          "title": "x"
        }
      }
    },
```

But the latter action inhibits the first one. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need distinct names for your selections, so perhaps you could use `"grid_x"` and `"grid_y"`.

And if you want the control key to toggle between these zoom modes, you can do so by using `"wheel![event.ctrlKey]"` for one, and `"wheel![!event.ctrlKey]"` for the other.

Here's a short example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegMYWQGcA6AK0IHsA7EAXwBoQBbAgawwAcKBLKqERgFMquCmF4BzeKFGoKyaSCgBPDoIxUKTXhHSMAZt0GowGAPLJuE3nUYAPRSrUYAjogh9uMKNwBu6gyMTDAAJeUJBLgB3QQUGEGVHVXU4EDcPH28-AJBDY1NUgFluVEFCAH01ZHKAcV05Glp4iNLcH2pFCUswcocEJWSMXihY310BEAAjXgKQQnxSwgmALwotDCiAC0FjAEIAbUF-PmI2tABpQWUAXQnhUXEqCSW4fZAHa-iu7h7E-qcUiBhqNxoxplRZvNdGUVmsmBttnt9rsjsIoKcoBcrrchCIxJIXm9Ep8mkA)):

```json
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Origin"},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Horsepower"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Miles_per_Gallon"}
  },
  "selection": {
    "grid_x": {
      "type": "interval",
      "bind": "scales",
      "zoom": "wheel![event.ctrlKey]",
      "encodings": ["x"]
    },
    "grid_y": {
      "type": "interval",
      "bind": "scales",
      "zoom": "wheel![!event.ctrlKey]",
      "encodings": ["y"]
    }
  }
}
```